# cpan vs cpanm vs cpm

Tags: perl

В чем принципиальное отличие от этих инсталлеров? И какой используете вы?

Comment: Мне кажется этот вопрос не форматен для SO из-за того что под ним нет реальной проблемы, а каждый ответ будет субъективен. Возможно ты не очень внимательно читал правила https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: нормально оформлен. я потом напишу ответ. может кому-то понадобится данный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [`cpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN/scripts/cpan) - модуль для интерактивной и автоматической инсталляции моделуй с CPAN.
2. [`cpanp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPANPLUS/bin/cpanp) - еще один установщик модулей с CPAN, скорость работы немного быстрее, чем классический [`cpan`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN/scripts/cpan).
3. [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus/fatscript.pm) - это более быстрый, и менее функциональный иснтрумент для работы с CPAN. Именно его рекомендуют использовать новичкам.
4. [`cpm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpm/script/cpm) - очень быстрый инструмент (как [утверждает](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CdpBV8BgPI4) создатель) для работы с CPAN. Он использует [Menlo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Menlo).